# Gradle Errors When Setting Up Multi Project / Composite Build

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, build, build.gradle

I'm trying to setup a multi-project/composite gradle build for a kotlin project I'm working on and am running into some errors. I have this in my settings.gradle file:

```
def projects = [
    'shared-library'
]

for (String relativeProject : projects) {
    File file = new File(settingsDir, "../$relativeProject")

    if (file.exists()) {
        include(relativeProject) 
        project(":$relativeProject").projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "../$relativeProject")
    }
}
```

When the project builds  I get this error:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':shared-library'.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file '/home/stormblessed/Soft/ApiGateway/build.gradle' line: 3
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.3.21']
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.3.21']
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:256)
... 135 more
Caused by: org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.InvalidPluginRequestException: Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version
```

What is weird is that I have this exact same setup for a Java project and the java plugin doesn't have a version associated with so that might have something to do with it not failing for java projects.

I read a github issue that described my same problem and the resolution suggested I use `includeBuild` instead of `include` and that worked except I now get a new error:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'api-gateway'.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':shared-library' could not be found.
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor426.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at settings_eft3sns2cik3i85f9zhag0eho.run(/home/stormblessed/Soft/Personal/api-gateway/settings.gradle:13)
```

I'm not sure really how to keep my projects independent while also grouping them together for sharing dependencies and compilation. How would I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: Using a _composite build_ to get rid of the "Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version" error message seems to be the right solution, for me it worked. For others having the same problem, you have to add `includeBuild <pathName>`to your toplevel _settings.gradle_ file. Then the two builds will be completely separate and versions of plugins won't clash.